# IIS 7 Basic authentication location issue

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7

I have a website on IIS 7 using Basic authentication. There are some pages that must be public. I added an this exception in a location element in the web.config and it looks like this:

```
   <location path="Errors">
    <system.webServer>
      <security>
        <authorization>
          <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
          <add accessType="Allow" users="*" />
        </authorization>
      </security>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
```

However, if I try to access some files from that folder, I get this error:

> HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized You are not authorized to view this
>   page due to invalid authentication headers. Detailed Error Information
>   Module IIS Web Core  Notification AuthenticateRequest  Handler
>   StaticFile  Error Code 0x80070005  Requested URL
>   http://srv/Errors/error401.htm  Physical Path
>   D:\www\MyApp\Errors\error401.htm  Logon Method Not yet determined 
>   Logon User Not yet determined

How can I have Basic Auth over my site, but allow everyone access on the Errors directory?

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, "?" is for anonymous users...  So turn on Anonymous authentication aswell and put this in your web.config... Hope it works for you...

*IIS7*

```
<location path="Errors">
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <authorization>
        <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
        <add accessType="Allow" users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</location>
```

*IIS6 (or IIS7 Classic mode)*

```
<location path="Errors">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="?" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

**EDIT**

I'm not sure removing the authenticatied users (*) for errors is a good idea, though... Authenticated users can get errors, too... Show them some love... ;)

**EDIT 2** *(Changed for Classic mode in IIS7)*

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work either. I have tried every combination of * and ? but nothing...

Comment: Is your app pool set to integrated mode?

Comment: That doesn't work either... I'm puzzled. I found this article http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/142/understanding-iis-7-url-authorization/#Differences Check the differences table. If I understood correctly, the way IIS Auth rules are evaluated, if you deny something on the parent, you cannot override it on the child, because the parent gets evaluated first. It doesn't really make any sense.